# A sequence of hops

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid, pygame, time-complexity

I currently have a game I am trying to create where a grid is used.

The player can either move horizontally then vertically or vertically then horizontally but the difficulty is in the form of the number of moves they can make in each direction in order to reach their goal.

For example, if we have a grid which is 4 rows by 5 columns (4X5) with the trophy being located in the 3rd row of the 4th column(3X4) then if the player can  move by 1 row and at most 2 columns at a time or move by at most 2 rows and 1 column at a time, then the shortest route to the trophy is in 3 moves.

I would like to know if there is a way to possibly develop an algorithm to calculate the shortest possible moves to the trophy point on the grid given they can move vertically then horizontally only a certain amount of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using some sort of premade pathfinding algorithm like A*.

There's a great introduction to A* in python at https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html.

If that doesn't work then you can just google "python pathfinding algorithm".